# CloudBlockBlob: DownloadTextAsync and UploadTextAsync and Metadata/Properties

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

As in the Documentation [azure doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-properties-metadata/) or [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob_methods.aspx) you have to call `FetchAttributesAsync()` to populate a CloudBlockBlob's metadata.

I've noticed that the Metadata also gets populated when I call `DownloadTextAsync()` and is written while I call `UploadTextAsync()`. Is this safe to use as that it won't change in future versions of the storage sdk? I can't really find any documentation that confirms that behaviour.

Sample:

```
        var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("testblob");

        blob.Metadata["testdata"] = "set";

        await blob.UploadTextAsync("content");

        blob.Metadata["notset"] = "set";

        blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("testblob");

        var content = await blob.DownloadTextAsync();
        // here content["testdata"] is set and content["notset"] is null
```

Thanks for information!

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by `Is this safe to use?`.

Comment: I can't find in the documentation that the metadata is set and I don't want to encounter any changes in future versions of the sdk.  (I know that this is probably 99.99% safe to use but maybe someone can point me to the documentation)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me try to explain what's happening with your code. See if that clarifies your doubts.

When you execute following code:

```
await blob.UploadTextAsync("content");
```

Essentially it calls [`Put Blob`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179451.aspx) REST API. As you can see from the REST API documentation, any metadata elements you specify by using `blob.Metadata["testdata"] = "set";` code gets passed on to the REST API in `x-ms-meta-testdata` header.

So when this code executes, the metadata is saved along with the blob.

When you execute the following line of code:

```
blob.Metadata["notset"] = "set";
```

Basically, the blob object's (which is of type `CloudBlockBlob`) [`Metadata`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.metadata(v=azure.10).aspx) property gets updated. This update happens only on the client side and nothing gets saved in the blob. In order to save it, you must call [`SetMetadataAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.setmetadataasync(v=azure.10).aspx).

Coming to the last part, when you execute following line of code:

```
var content = await blob.DownloadTextAsync();
```

Essentially it calls [`Get Blob`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179440.aspx) REST API. As you can see from the REST API documentation, this operation also returns the metadata for the blob in response headers. Azure Storage Client library then updates the `Metadata` property of your `blob` using the data it received as response to the REST API call.